# What does "nearest bottom neighbor" mean in layman terms when using auto layout?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

I've noticed the term nearest bottom neighbor used in different contexts when following tutorials on building interfaces in interface builder.  Does the nearest bottom neighbor mean, if I come in contact with a view on the way down to the bottom safe area line then that would be the nearest neighbor?

An example tutorial can be found here: 
[Auto Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the very special circumstance where you use this popover to form constraints from a selected view...

[image]

... how does the dialog know what you want to constrain *to* in a given direction? It doesn’t. So it just makes a rule that if you pick a direction it will constrain this view to the first view whose edge it comes to in that direction. The dialog terms that the “nearest neighbor”.

Thus, for the downward direction, we could call that view this view’s “nearest bottom neighbor”.

(Personally, I think there is so much limitation, confusion, indeterminacy, and inconvenience in that popover, that I *never* use it to form constraints. I can’t tell you what to do, but perhaps that’s a useful perspective at least. If you go the longer route and *draw* the constraint by control-dragging from one view to another, you know exactly what you're doing; so that's how I always do it, even if it takes a little more work to configure the constraints after creating them.)

Comment: Interesting fun facts to know.  Can I ask if constrain to margins is checked, are margins the same as "the safe area"?

Comment: Yes you can ask and no they are not!